# On Chrome Extension "popup" open/focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I determine if the popup window was opened? E.g. someone clicked on the extension (chrome.browserAction), the window open and I want to show a loading sign inside the popup every time someone does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can register [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event listener for browserAction.

   ```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
       // do what you want
   });
   ```
2. You can also listen to [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event in popup page.

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
       // do what you want
   };
   ```